# How long does the Golden Age started by Taj Mahal in Civ5 last?

Tags: civilization-5

I just built the Taj Mahal wonder in Civ5 on a normal sized map with normal game speed and Prince difficulty and the game is displaying the Golden Age it just started will last for 21 turns.

21 turns seems incredibly powerful, given that the Golden Ages for great people last (I think) 10 turns to *begin* with. (And at my current game stage 5 or 6 turns.)

Is this correct or is the gaming displaying a bogus value? (Or would you consider this a balancing bug?)

---

Addendum: Playing as Washington and I have the Chichen Itza wonder. (Which I conquered, so I wasn't even really aware I had it ;-)

Comment: Are you playing as Persia? There seems to be some bugs with how Golden-Age extending abilities work off each other.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The base number of turn for the Taj Mahal is 15 a turn Golden Age. The Chichen Itza world wonder will increase that number by 50% (= 22 turns).

Building the Taj Mahal as Darius resulted in a Golden Age of 33 turns (should only be 50% longer). Darius with Chichen Itza resulted in a 49 turn Golden Age.

The base value seems reasonably balanced to me, maybe a bit too powerful. With Chichen Itza it is very powerful, but Taj Mahal with Darius is just outright overpowered, or even broken.

Comment: What the hell, 49 turns?! Amazing :)

Comment: 60 turns at epic speed =)